# how to create log output on wordpress white screen of death

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a white screen of death in wordpress with a custom message.  It's a live hosted site and I'm just debugging someone else's plugin, so all I want to do is print some messages showing me what data it's collecting so I can get it work.  I'm not concerned that it's live and I have no interest in figuring out how to change the wp-config.php or .ini files or whatever.  I just want a quick debug message displayed to the screen.

Comment: Turn on wp debug? It's changing ONE value in wp-config.php to true... You could also add various echo and print_r statements to output the plugin messages.

Comment: I got the impression that I could not change wp-config from the ui.  Am I wrong?  And where does the echo output go?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `echo` just prevents normal page rendering outputs your data to the white screen.  I should have just tried it.  Thanks Big Chris.